# How can I multiply two arrays like [1,2,3] and [4,5,6] in quantum computing aspects?

Tags: quantum-gate, qiskit, programming, quantum-algorithms, measurement

Multiplication of two arrays in quantum computing.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Quantum Computing SE. Could you please add more details? Do you want to multiply binary numbers or their decimal equivalents? Are you looking for multiplicating circuit analog to classical computer or purely quantum approach?

Comment: @MartinVesely I am looking for purely quantum approach

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking how to multiply two arrays $u = [1,2,3]$ and $v = [4,5,6]$ in Qiskit setting  then you can do this as would normally do... by import numpy.

```
import numpy as np
u = [1,2,3]
v = [4,5,6]
product_uv = np.multiply(u,v)
```

---

If that is not what you are asking for... but rather on how the quantum processor multiply two arrays, then think about about how a classical processor multiply two arrays... and make all those operations reversible...

Quantum computers are not meant to replace classical computers. They are meant to solve certain hard problems that classical computers can't efficiently (at least we haven't figure out a way to do it yet)... but we are not even there yet.

If you want to learn more about quantum computing, I suggest the [Qiskit Textbook](https://qiskit.org/textbook/preface.html), and Prof. John Preskill's [Lecture note](http://theory.caltech.edu/%7Epreskill/ph229/notes/)  or [this textbook](http://mmrc.amss.cas.cn/tlb/201702/W020170224608149940643.pdf).

Comment: I actually meant how quantum processor multiply two arrays..how can I make those operations reversible?

Comment: @KarakoottilDasan Since the [NAND gate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAND_gate) is universal for classical computation, The most straightforward way to do this is create a circuit that performs array multiplication using only NAND gates and replace these NAND gates with the [Toffoli gates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toffoli_gate).

Comment: Thanks, @VictoryOmole. I have another doubt regarding exponential operation. In python we have Numpy.exp() to perform exponential operation.How can I do that in quantum computing?

Comment: I haven't read this paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/0407079.pdf; but take a look at page 6 of it `The circuit for the approximate calculus` and let me know if it helps.

Comment: @VictoryOmole Yes its find helpful..But I don't know how to code that in qiskit